# Function in if statement

Tags: jquery

I have a class var Page() = {...
and inside I have functions, like the one below. But I'm not sure how to write a function to toggle two bg images if their class is 'vg-slideshow'. It's not working.

```
initFeaturedImages : function () {
            $('.story-page').each(function () {
                var $fImg = $(this).find('.right img');
                if ($fImg.length) {
                    var src = $fImg[0].src;
                    var flipimgsrc = $fImg.data('flipimg');  
                    var type = $fImg[0].className;
                    $($fImg[0]).hide();
                    var $bg = $fImg.parents('.story-page').find('.left');

                    var nextImg = 0; var bgImgs = new Array(src, flipimgsrc);

                    //(typeof type !== 'undefined' && type !== false && type == 'bg') 
                    if (type && type === 'bg') {
                        $bg.css('background-image','url("'+ src +'")');
                    }
                    else if (type && type === 'bg-slideshow') {

                        var doBg = function () {
                             $bg.css('background-image','url("'+ bgImgs[nextImg++] +'")').fadeIn(500, function () { setTimeout( doBg, 1000 ); });
                        };
                    }
                    else if (type && type === 'flip') {
                        //var titlesrc = (title) ? "<li>"+title+"</li>" : "" ;
                        $bg.append('<div id="fc-slideshow" class="fc-slideshow"><ul class="fc-slides"><li><img src="'+src+'" /></li><li><img src="'+flipimgsrc+'" /></li></ul></div>'); 
                    }
                    else if (type && type === 'svg') {
                        $.get(src, function(data) {
                            var $svg = $(data);

                            $bg.append($svg);
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $bg.append('<img src="'+src+'" />'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your doBg function, but here is one thing that stands out already:

`var doBg` is declared inside the if statement, and never called in the `if` statement. You can't call it outside of the `if` statement because Javascript is [lexically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope). Hence,

```
 var doBg = function () {
     $bg.css('background-image','url("'+ bgImgs[nextImg++] +'")').fadeIn(500, function () { setTimeout( doBg, 1000 ); });
};
```

does nothing.

I also believe you have mismatching parenthesis.

Comment: It's called inside `fadeIn(500, function () { setTimeout( doBg, 1000 ); });`

Comment: You have defined `doBg` to be a function, but `doBg` is never called, hence the code inside `doBg` is never called. To invoke `fadeIn` you would need to call `doBg()`, but you never do that.

Comment: But inside `setTimeout(doBg, 1000)`?

Comment: When is `setTimeout` invoked though? You need to invoke `doBg` before `setTimeout` is invoked.

Comment: Have you verified that the timeout is actually calling doBg?  Try a console.log or alert in there and see if it's ever being called.  Also, once that `$bg` is faded in, it's not going to "fade in" again, unless you set the opacity to 0.

Comment: I'm confused as where to call doBg ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to the bottom of your code inside the if statement that defines doBg():

```
   doBg();
```